# CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses() always returns null

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I  recently submitted an UWP app to the store. Everything works fine except the IAP. CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses() always returns null, even though there are 5 IAP items on my Dashboard.

All the 5 IAPs are submitted and show "In the Store" status. But, They don't show up on the app. I tried setting the visibility of the IAPs to "unavailable" and then resubmitted them. Still no change.

It has been over 72 hours since I submitted the app to the store.

What could be the problem? I tried contacting MS but I am yet to receive any reply from them. I am losing some potential customers because of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new update and submitted it to the store without changing anything (packages, description, etc...). After it got published, I did the same for all IAPs.

After waiting for a couple of days, The IAPs work now and the `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses()` returns all the IAPs.